# Magento 1.9 - Product Description not displaying in product view page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

In have Magento version 1.9 and I added product description for my product in Catalog => Manage Products => General Tab => Description *.
The problem is that the product description is not displaying in product view page. The issue is only there for some products.

I tried the following:

1. Catalog => Manage Products => General Tab => Status * => Enabled
2. Catalog => Manage Products => General Tab => Visibility * => Catalog, Search
3. Catalog => Manage Products => Choose Store View: => Default values
4. Catalog => Manage Products => Inventory => Stock Availability => In Stock and Qty > 0
5. Catalog => Manage Products => Website => Main Website
6. Selected categories in Catalog => Manage Products => Categories

Also I have flushed Magento cache and re-indexed. Still I'm not able to view the description in product view page. When I checked with firebug the products which displayed properly had a classes `last current` in the html tag `<dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs"> <dd class="tab-container last current">` , but those classes are missing in products which faces this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. The issue was caused by a slider module for displaying relative products which was just below the description div. I was able to find a JavaScript error in the console view but only for these products.

Thanks to all Who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to display product description:

```
<?php
$my_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
echo $my_product->getDescription();
?>
```